# Overlay toolbar on top of activity content

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm using the AppCompat v21 library to create a Lollipop-like interface in my android app. 
 So far it's working great.

Now I want to have to toolbar appear on top of my content in one of my activities. 
However, I cannot get it to work. This is what I have so far:

**Layout of activity:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/myAppTheme">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_setlist_top"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Layout of toolbar:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/MyActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
```

**Theme:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="myAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primaryColor2</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/primaryColor2</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setlist);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to place the toolbar on top of your content you can use a FrameLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:background="#000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_setlist_top"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, that dit it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me overcome the same problem. However one thing is not yet clear - Is it really essential to use a FrameLayout? Can't it be done using relative or linear layout?

Comment: @webgenius yes it can, using a relative layout. The same concept.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you're acquiring a reference to the toolbar view in your layout anywhere. You need to find the view first, then pass that reference to the `setSupportActionBar` method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_setlist);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Oops, I actually have that line, but it must have gotten lost during copying to this website. Edited the code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when you say "Now I want to have to toolbar appear on top of my content in one of my activities" you are trying to use the Toolbar as your activity's ActionBar (instead of the old/original ActionBar) you must make your theme's parent theme "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" instead of your current setting *.Light.DarkActionBar. Hope this helps.

Comment: That solved a problem I had with the color of the title in the toolbar, but unfortunately the toolbar is still pushing down the imageview, instead of being on top of it. Could it be a problem in my layout XML?